# Coffeescript gives error when installing

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

```
Joeris-MacBook-Pro:~ Joericblom$ npm install -g coffee-script
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "coffee-script"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/coffee
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/coffee'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/coffee']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/coffee' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/coffee'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/coffee']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/bin/coffee' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Joericblom/npm-debug.log
Joeris-MacBook-Pro:~ Joericblom$
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error says: `Error: EACCES: permission denied`.

You'll need admin rights to install globally, so you need to prepend your command with `sudo`.
Like this: `sudo npm install -g coffee-script`

Comment: I did, now i get this: 

/usr/local/bin/cake -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
/usr/local/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
coffee-script@1.10.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script

Is it installed now? Im new to mac, so i dont really know when to get the confirmation message.

Comment: @JoeriBlom Looks like it. Try to type `coffee -h` for something to see if you get the help page.